# How to leave a team on itunes connect?

Tags: iphone, app-store-connect, membership

I'm in multiple teams in iTunes Connect and want to leave one of these teams. I can't connect with the administrator of that team. How to do that?
**P.S.** [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8825430/how-do-you-leave-a-team-when-a-member-of-multiple-teams-on-iphone-developer-prog) answer is for Developer site only.

Answer (score 82, accepted):

Click on "Edit Profile" on the top right of App Store Connect while you are on the team you want to leave. Scroll down to the bottom and select "Leave Team".

Comment: The question is about iTunesConnect

Comment: iTunes Connect was rebranded to App Store Connect this year as far as I am aware

Comment: Funny is that I left but still I am have that company as if I am there but not figuring in user lists so maybe it needs some time to  recognize I am out or what...... :)

Comment: Thanks. This works for me.

Comment: I wish this worked for me, but I do not have an Edit Profile option.  The only option I get is "Sign Out"

Comment: This is no "Leave Team" option as of April 2023.

Comment: I still see the option in June 2023. @Renetik I left but I still see the company there, what worked for you?

Comment: The answer is still valid as of September 2023, the other users could have problems with their account types on the team, maybe?